# How to debug the NDK in eclipse,I want to use Sequoyah to debug my native vode,but there are some problems?

Tags: android, debugging, native, android-ndk

A step-by-step guide for debugging native code, by Carlos Souto
the website is

http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/documentation/native_debug.php

My question

There are a couple of files that don't seem to be present that are needed (I
guess).
the one snag is in step 5 within Configurations
05) On the "Main" tab: 
the Field C/C++ Application: `$PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi/app_process`

There is no app_process file at that path.  All I have in the armeabi directory
is:

```
libskychart.so // the shared library I'm building with the jni code.
```

Where is the app_process file supposed to come from (or do I substitute the
shared lib for "ap_process")?

The other snag is in step 8:
08) GDB command file: `$PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi/gdb2.setup`

as before, there is no gdb2.setup file here.  Where does that come from?

please do me a favour how can i get above two files?

Answer (score 1):

The app_process and gdb.setup files are created for you (see the links below). I only recently went through all this for the first time and failed with Sequoyah, but the (similar) approach given here worked for me:

Part 1: http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/

Part 2 (for debugging): http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/